# When can this condition on linear codes be satisfied?

Tags: coding-theory

It would be useful to me to have a result of the following kind (which I would need to generalize, but this case is already interesting). Let $r<n$ be positive integers and let $\delta>0$ be a fixed constant such as 1/100. Does there exist a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb F_2^n$ that is a $\delta r$-separated $r$-net? That is, I would like every vector to have Hamming distance at most $r$ from some $v\in V$ and any two distinct vectors in $V$ to have distance at least $\delta r$ from each other.

This feels like the kind of thing that coding theorists ought to know about, but what comes up when I do a Google search is more to do with the dimension of $V$ than with whether it is a good net. But perhaps it comes into the "known to be hard" category.

I am interested in more or less the full range of $r$ for given $n$: the existence of such a linear code for some specific $r$ would be interesting but not enough for my eventual purposes.

Comment: since the answer states that  linear vs nonlinear codes make no difference to your question, I was wondering what the direction of your generalization might be, if you don't mind sharing

Comment: Just to make sure you have heard of the coding theory terminology. If $V$ is a code, $r$ is called its *covering radius* - the balls of radius $r$ centered at the points of $V$ cover the whole space. The covering radius is a well-studied parameter. A lot is known about it for example for BCH-codes. Don't know if the range of parameters available from there fits your purposes that well. Coding theorists often want the covering radius to be small also. For efficiency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any maximal $r$-separated set is an $r$-net, otherwise you can augment it with a non-covered point.

But the same holds for linear codes! If a subspace $V$ is $r$-separated but not an $r$-net, you may take a far point $u$: then $\langle V,u\rangle$ is still $r$-separated. So a maximal $V$ fits.

Comment: Ah, thank you -- I missed that easy argument, despite being aware of similar arguments! I now need to think about the extent to which it can be generalized to give me what I want.

Answer (score 2):

As an example I describe what is known about the BCH-codes for the purposes of this question. Just to give an idea of the type of results that are known. I suspect that they are not very useful for the full range of parameters here.

Let us specify a natural number $m$, and let $n=2^m-1$. Let us further specify the parameter $t$ (=the number of bit errors the code can correct). The BCH-code (more accurately, a narrow sense, primitive BCH-code) with *designed minimum distance* $d_{des}=2t+1$ is a vector space $V(m,t)\subset \Bbb{F}_2^n$ has minimum Hamming distance $d_{min}\ge d_{des}$ and dimension 
$$k(m,t)=\dim V(m,t)\ge n-mt.$$
The other parameter of interest here is the *covering radius* $\rho(m,t)$ of $V(m,t)$. That is, the smallest integer $\rho$ such that every point of $\Bbb{F}_2^n$ is within Hamming distance $\rho$ of a vector from the subspace $V(m,t)$.
Quite a bit is known about $\rho(m,t)$. This revolves around the solvability of systems of equations over $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$.

- In 1987 Tietäväinen proved that $\rho(m,t)\le 2t$ whenever $(2t-1)^{4t+2}\le 2^m$. This places a rather high demand on $m$, and that may prove to be the downfall of the use of BCH-codes here.
- In most cases (and also asymptotically) the true covering radius is $\rho=2t-1$, a result of Vladuts & Skorobogatov. The length from which on this holds has been brought down by a number of authors since.
- Usually $\rho\ge2t-1$ follows from the so called supercode lemma. That is easy to describe. We always have $V(m,t)\subseteq V(m,t-1)$. Whenever the inclusion here is strict, and the code $V(m,t-1)$ contains a vector $x$ of Hamming weight $2t-1$ (both of these are true often enough), then $x$ obviously cannot be at a distance $<2t-1$ from a vector of $V(m,t)$, proving the claim.
- A bit of searching pointed me to a paper by F. Levy-dit-Vehel and S. Litsyn that appeared in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 42(3) in May '96. They described the known results at that time.
- So for BCH-codes the covering radius is often relatively close to the minimum distance (if it were higher, we could make the code bigger). Meaning that your parameter $\delta$ can be made close to $1$.
- The catch is that the BCH-codes are known to be "asymptotically bad". From the inequality of the dimension we see that $t$ is usually bounded to be at most something like $n/\log_2n$. Also the bounds on $\rho$ don't apply to very small BCH-codes.

Another family of codes whose covering radii have been studied extensively consists of the Reed-Muller codes. The first order Reed-Muller codes in particular could be useful for your purpose.

> The main reason you may not have found a lot of information is that for coding theoretical purposes, whenever $\rho>d_{min}$ the code becomes immediately non-interesting. I guess that's the content of Ilya Bogdanov's answer in different language.